# Trigger event handler off SharePoint list column change

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to see if it's possible to fire an event handler when a list column is changed.  For example, if I have a choice column with options A,B,C.  If I add an option for D, is it possible to trigger an event off that?  If so, how can I tell what was changed in the list?

I found SPListEventReceiver and I see FieldUpdating/ed but I'm not really sure how to use it.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean when choice column schema has changed (i.e editing field in field settings page) or user just adds a custom value to dropdown field when adding list item?

Comment: I am looking to trigger off of when a choice column is edited in the list settings.  If I go into the list settings, edit a column, and add an additional dropdown choice, is this something I can fire an event from?

Answer (score 0):

Event Receivers are used when you want to track changes to the values of an item. In your case, you cannot use Event handlers.

Comment: Do I have any options for list setting changes?

Comment: I am still searching for something for you :-). Nothing out of the box.

Comment: Thanks!  To give some background on why I want this, I'm working with synchronizing a parent list with multiple child lists.  I have the code done when items are added/updated/deleted but I wanted to see if I could sync any structure changes so that new columns or updated columns would get pushed down to the child lists.

Comment: One option is to write a timer job and check the parent list and child lists periodically or have a custom webpart/app page for admins to mnually start a sync process.

Comment: A manual sync may do the trick as I don't foresee this happening a lot.  I'm guessing that SPFieldCollection is what I need to hook in to to modify column settings?

Comment: @Mike Thats why you should use content types and use site columns. In that way if you change your content type, these changes are pushed down to any list where that content type is used, for all items that are of that content type.